# Why do "in prep" papers behave differently from "year'd" ones?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Someone asked me to troubleshoot a LaTeX+BibTeX document. The problem, I've found, boils down to an abuse of the author-year system in the citations in the following way:

```
@article{W1,
   author = {Waldo, W},
   title = {First paper},
   year = {in prep. }
}
@article{W2,
   author = {Waldo, W},
   title = {Second paper},
   year = {in prep. }
}
```

With the actual document looking like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
Cite first \cite{W1}. Cite second \cite{W2}. Cite both \cite{W1,W2}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

For the single citations, it will look correct:

> Cite first Waldo [in prep.a]. Cite second Waldo [in prep.b].

But for the two items, it looks like

> Cite both Waldo [in prep.a,i]

whereas the author of the document expects it to read

> Cite both Waldo [in prep.a,b]

**Remark**
If you replace the "in prep" in the bibtex file above by a made up year, say 2038, the document shows correctly

> Cite both Waldo [2038a,b]

**Questions**:

1. Why did the numbering switch from alphabetical to roman, and restart from 1?
2. Most likely this is the incorrect way of abusing the author-year citation style from NatBib to include "in prep" papers. Is there a better way? Or a way to hack this so it would work? The goal is for published papers to show "Author [year]" and for manuscripts in preparation to show "Author [in prep.]", with multiple manuscripts by the same author correctly handled.

Comment: @Willy Wong - don't know what style of referencing you are using, but at least according to APA 6th, the in-text citation should be the year of the draft you read - not in preparation (p. 211-22 in the manual). In the reference list, however, it should say "Manuscript in preparation".

Comment: @Tormod: APA has nothing to do with this question (it is not the style guide used for the preparation of this document). The output referred to in the question text **is** the desired output: for published paper it should show "Author [year]", and for in prep paper it should read "Author [in prep.]" or "Author [in prep.b]" if it is the second of a list of manuscripts in preparation.

Comment: The question is about why for years, Natbib correctly produces "Author [1997a,b]", but for manuscripts in prep it shows "Author [in prep.a,i]", and how to fix it. I've edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ad 1: The letter "i" in your example is not a roman 1, but the first non-numerical character in the `year` field ("in prep. "). Replace the contents of `year` with "still in prep. ", and your example will change to "Waldo [still in prep.a,s]". This is caused by the macro `\NAT@parse@date` with the following definition:

```
\def\NAT@parse@date#1#2#3#4#5#6@@{%
  \ifnum\the\catcode`#1=11\def\NAT@year{}\def\NAT@exlab{#1}\else
  \ifnum\the\catcode`#2=11\def\NAT@year{#1}\def\NAT@exlab{#2}\else
  \ifnum\the\catcode`#3=11\def\NAT@year{#1#2}\def\NAT@exlab{#3}\else
  \ifnum\the\catcode`#4=11\def\NAT@year{#1#2#3}\def\NAT@exlab{#4}\else
    \def\NAT@year{#1#2#3#4}\def\NAT@exlab{{#5}}\fi\fi\fi\fi}
```

Ad 2: Maybe someone is able to hack `natbib` internals so your example would work. I prefer to use (surprise) [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{% = the 'a' in 'Jones 1995a'
  \mknumalph{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{W1,
   author = {Waldo, W},
   title = {First paper},
   year = {in prep. }
}
@misc{W2,
   author = {Waldo, W},
   title = {Second paper},
   year = {in prep. }
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Cite first \textcite{W1}. Cite second \textcite{W2}. Cite both \textcite{W1,W2}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yet another reason to switch to biblatex. (Unfortunately that is not my document that is being prepared yada yada.) Thanks for the diagnosis: while it doesn't solve the problem, it cleared up where the problem is (and so we were able to work around it).